# slideup after fading out function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#error').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000).slideUp();
    });
</script>
```

I got part of it working, however it doesn't slide up after it has faded out.

EDIT:

I want the content below this div to slide after the div has faded out.. Code:

```
    $(function() {
    $('#error').delay(3000).fadeOut(2000).animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, "slow", function(){
                        $(this).slideUp();
    });
});
```

it's still going up fast.

Comment: Why not combine them....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first fadeout the element with **animate**, than on the **callback** *(when the fade is completed)*, you do the **slideUp**.

```
$(function() {
    $('#error').delay(1000).animate({opacity: 0}, 100, "linear", function() {
        $('#error').slideUp();
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4HT25/

Comment: An element that is faded out, can't be slide up. It's already display none at that point...

Comment: i should've worded this better. I want it to slide up once it's faded out. Like when the div is faded out, instead of the content below it coming up fast, isn't their a way for it to slowly slide up? @simon arnold?

Comment: I updated my example according to your edit. You first fadeout the element with animate, than on the callback (when the fade is completed) the slideUp happen.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/XhXDq/3/

```
jQuery("#outer").animate({opacity: 0}, 1000).slideUp();
```

Comment: @jason I don't want a click function though. This div will fade out on it's own. How can i remove the click function?

Answer (score 0):

Use fadeTo instead.   To zero

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#error').delay(1000).fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp();
    });
</script>
```